# Should I put any coefficient in front of $x^4$, or does it matter?

Tags: polynomials, roots, quartics

I was trying to solve the problem:
Given that a and b are distinct positive numbers, find a polynomial P(x) such that the derivatives of $P(x)e^{-x^2}$ is zero for $x=0, x=a, x=-a, x=b, x=-b$.

We need to find the polynomial of p(x) in terms of a and b obviously.

What I did is:
We know $P’(x) - 2xP(x)=kx(x^2-a^2)(x^2-b^2)$. 
Now, the next step is to assume the terms in P(X). So what I did is I assume: 
$P(x)=\alpha x^4 + \beta x^3 + cx^2 + dx + g$

However, I saw the mark scheme, the P(x) should be assumed to be:
$x^4 +\beta x^3 +cx^2 + dx +g$, which means the coefficient should be 1 in front of the $x^4$. May I know why is this so? Or it is still be corrected if I put a constant in front of the $x^4$ term.

Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you find a $P(x)$ that works, any constant times $P(x)$ will work as well because it will just multiply all the $0$s you are producing.  You might as well divide by the coefficient of $x^4$ for standardization.  Alternately, you could delete $k$ from your expression, which would give perhaps a different standardization.

You have six parameters in the solution, $\alpha, \beta, c,d,g,k$ and five equations for the degrees $0$ through $4$ in your equation, so if you do not delete $\alpha$ or $k$ (or one of the others) you will not have a unique solution.

Comment: Thank you very much. So I could either add a k or give a constant in front of $x^4$ for standardization. Is it?

Comment: But eventually, k is better, since it would factorize out.

Comment: But, I still don’t understand, if k is factorize out, why should I assume terms in $x^3, x^2, x,$ It is so confusing. Why is assuming no constants is legit.

Comment: Your assumption of a quartic comes from the fact that you have five constraints to satisfy, so need five free parameters to do that.  I believe the symmetry of the problem leads to $\beta=d=0$.  There is no mathematical reason you could not delete $c$ or $g$, but it is more common to consider monic polynomials when possible.  The real point is that you have one parameter too many.

Comment: Hello, sir, the 5 constraints are the five solutions? So this would imply that we should have 5 parameter in order to produce a unique solution. Right? So, can I assume $\alpha x^4 + x^3 + \beta x^2 +dx+g$. In this case, I also have 5 parameters. Is this true? Thank you very much for you’re great help, sir.

Comment: Yes, the five constraints are the five roots.  Yes, I believe you could, but then you should delete $k$ from your equation.  I haven't tried it, but I believe it will work as well.  If you double the polynomial you will double $k$.d  Removing $k$ is normalizing the polynomial by setting $k$ to $1$.

Comment: Thank you very much. @Ross Millikan, sir. So, the constants are not important, as it can be tested, the most important thing is that the number of parameters equate to the number of roots.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to assume $P$ is monic if that was not required, except to make your life easier. Multiplying a polynomial by a constant does not affect the zeroes of its derivative, after all.

Comment: Thank you very much. But how does assuming P is monic is legit, or assuming constants in front of other terms is legit. I am so confusing about this....

Comment: Either way is "legit", because of the point I explained in the answer: this doesn't affect the roots of $P'$. I would say it would be unfair to penalize you for letting $P$ have a leading coefficient other than $1$, but as Ross says you may end up having to invent some value for one of the parameters to finish the problem!